# QGIS does not recognize Arc-created shapefile CRS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I create a new point shapefile in QGIS (2.12) with **EPSG:2927**.  When I view the Layer's Properties, the CRS is correctly listed as EPSG:2927. Happy!

I then create a second point shapefile in Arc Catalog (10.0) using the same CRS.  However, when this shapefile is added to QGIS, the Layer Properties reports **USER:100002**.  Sad...

Why doesn't QGIS correctly recognize the Arc-created CRS, and what can I do to correct this reporting difference?

I should note that the Arcmap point features are correctly located when viewed in QGIS.

Comment: QGIS recognized the CRS, but treated it as custom, that's why it has user-code (10000x) and your points are ok. Please add contents of prj-files that both QGIS and Arc Catalog added.

Comment: Esri uses the original WKT standard with some modifications. It's likely the CRS names and/or projection parameters don't match qgis's.

Answer (score 3):

ARCGIS and QGIS use different parameter code if I'm correct (or they are protected as in MAPINFO). When importing a Arcmap layer to QGIS it will make a 'custom' CRS based on the parameters from the Arc shapefiles. You can check if the parameters are the same in QGIS. Or you can copy the whole layer with the correct CRS: Right mouse click on the layer--> save layer as. It will ask you which CRS you want to give the new layer. Hope this solves the problem.

Comment: Another option is, instead of copying the layer and setting the CRS, you can Define the CSR of the shapefile in QGis (Vector / Data Management / Define Current Projection). That tool has saved me quite a bit...