# QGIS creating user CRS rather than using UK National grid

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

Does anyone have any issues using QGIS (current version 2.12.1 on mac) with the British National Grid CRS (EPSG 27700)?

All of my data is held in BNG and my workspaces are set up to default to BNG when I create new datasets. However, almost every time I create a new dataset (raster or vector) QGIS defaults to creating a user generated CRS; an example in the image below.  These are always slightly out of sync with the 27700 data but shift back if you change the CRS to 27700.  Sometimes I'll finish working with 10 different user CRSs.

Is this something that I'm doing or is this a bug?  I can't remember whether this has ever happened on previous versions of QGIS.

[image: Incorrect CRS example]

Comment: 2.12.1 is not the current version - try 2.14 or 2.16. I recall seeing this years ago but not recently. Mostly caused by importing ArcMap generated .proj files

Comment: As per this question (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172093/qgis-does-not-recognize-arc-created-shapefile-crs?rq=1) - this is all happening within Q though.  I'll try the latest version and see if it clears up.

Answer (score 1):

There is no bug: I met this problem before with Russian coordinate systems. My data had been created in MapInfo and then it was used in QGIS. I noticed a slight difference in parameters of towgs84 transformation. This difference caused that QGIS didn't recognized the original CRS.

For solving this issue I manually set the correct CRS (without reprojecting).

So it is all about how different software define parameters of CRS.

Comment: This happens to me even if I create a shapefile in QGIS, close the workspace, and then re-add the dataset.  It isn't critical, just slightly annoying.